# Create animation of an image overlaid with a circle and cross

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create an animation, in which each individual frame making up the animation comprises an image overlaid with a transparent circle and central cross-hairs. At each new frame everything should update (i.e. the image changes, and the circle and cross-hairs both move). Basically, I want to check that I can track moving features in the image.

I can update the cross but the image and and circle are more problematic. I searched for previous answers that might help (and tried a few things suggested) but nothing has worked yet. Any help would be great - thanks!

p.s. currently I initialise the plot before starting the animation as well as having a init_func (I was simply trying both and have left both in).

```
import scipy as sp, numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


def movie(images, xpos, ypos, nim=100, nxy=10):
    """
    nim = no. of images
    nxy = no. of pixels along x and y axes in each image
    images = array of shape nim x nxy x nxy. i.e. 100 images of 10x10 pixels
    xpos = x-coordinate of centre of circle (and cross-hairs). Array of length nim
    ypos = y-coordinate of centre of circle (and cross-hairs). Array of length nim
    """

    # set up figure
    fig = plt.figure(1, (10,10))
    plt.clf()
    fig.set_dpi(100)


    # initialise plot before running animation        
    im = plt.imshow([[],[]], interpolation='nearest', cmap='hot', origin='lower')
    circ = plt.Circle(([], []), 3, color='c', fill=False, lw=2)
    cross, = plt.plot([], [], 'cx', ms=7, mew=2)


    # initial function to 'populate' plot with empty image, circle and cross hairs for animation
    def init_movie():
        """  """
        im = plt.imshow([[],[]], interpolation='nearest', cmap='hot', origin='lower')
        circ = plt.Circle(([], []), 3, color='c', fill=False, lw=2)
        cross, = plt.plot([], [], 'cx', ms=7, mew=2)
        return im, circ, cross, 


    # animation function: update the image, and the locations of the circle and central cross hairs
    def animate_movie(i):
        """  """
        im.set_data( images[i] )
        circ.centre = (xpos[i], ypos[i])
        cross.set_data( xpos[i], ypos[i] )
        return im, circ, cross,


    # run animation
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate_movie, init_func=init_movie, 
                                   frames=nim, interval=100, blit=True)


    # save animation
    anim.save('animation.mp4', fps=10, \
              extra_args=['-vcodec', 'h264', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p'])


    plt.show()

    return
```